# How to filter rows that contain a string in any column in a dataframe

Tags: r

Using the `mtcars` dataframe, how can I get a new dataframe that contains the string "3"

So far I have:

```
mtcars<-lapply(mtcars, function(x) as.character(x))
myindices<-sapply(mtcars, function(x) { grep("3",x, ignore.case = TRUE) })
```

This gives me a list of indices. How do I just get a filtered dataframe from the original.

Feel free to criticise my approach, it is the end result that I am really interested in

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Finding rows that have the digit 3 somewhere within them?

Answer (score 7):

We can use `filter_all` from `dplyr`. This returns a dataframe with rows that has at least one column containing the string "3":

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(grepl("3", .)))
```

If we want a dataframe with rows that has *all* columns containing the string "3". We use `all_vars` instead of `any_vars`:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(grepl("3", .)))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can uses `grepl` with `Reduce` from `base R`

```
out <- mtcars[Reduce(`|`, lapply(mtcars, grepl, pattern = "3")),]
dim(out)
#[1] 31 11
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to your `sapply` solution:

```
mtcars[sapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(i) any(grepl("3", mtcars[i,], fixed = T))),]
```

Or, you could do this as well:

```
mtcars[grepl("3", do.call(paste0, mtcars), fixed = T),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R solution:

```
mtcars[apply(mtcars,1,function(x) grepl("3",paste(x,collapse=""))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `toString`.

```
mtcars.3 <- mtcars[grep("3", apply(mtcars, 1, toString)), ]
```

*Check:*

```
rbind(mtcars=dim(mtcars), mtcars.3=dim(mtcars.3))
         [,1] [,2]
mtcars     32   11
mtcars.3   31   11
```